# Symfony, route conflicts between controller and bundle

Tags: symfony, elfinder

For example simple controller:

```html
    /**
     * @Route("/{identifier}", name="page")
     */
    public function page(Request $request, string $identifier)
    {
        $page = $this->pageRepository->findOneBy(['identifier' => $identifier]);

        if (!$page || !$page->getEnabled()) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException();
        }
        
         return $this->render('cms/index.html.twig', []);
     }
```

And a have a bundle to manage images from admin page elfinder, which will enter the **/elfinder** link.

And instead of getting the bundle controller, my controller gets.

```
/{identifier} === /elfinder
```

How do people usually act in such situations?

I tried to set different priority, but it does not help

Comment: You could modify your route to: /your-site/module/{identifier}, AND accept only numerics param for that rule. Like:  @Route("/my-site/module/{identifier}", name="page", requirements={"identifier"="\d+"}

Comment: But the idea was to leave the first level. And the identifier can be both letters and numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding your controllers with the priority required in the annotations.yaml file. Thus, if you get a 404 in the first one, Symfony will try to open the route from the next controller

Add your controllers to `config/routes/annotations.yaml`

```
page:
    resource: App\Controller\_YourFistController_
    type: annotation

elfinder:
    resource: FM\ElfinderBundle\Controller\ElFinderController
    type: annotation
```

---

Or if this option does not suit you, then you can try the optional parameter `priority`. [symfony doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#priority-parameter)

Add to config file `config/routes.yaml`:

```
elfinder:
    path: /elfinder/{instance}/{homeFolder}
    priority: 2
    controller: FM\ElfinderBundle\Controller\ElFinderController::show
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it somehow dynamically, in case I decide to delete the bundle?

Comment: @AlexReid I can't say for sure.) But, if this option doesn't suit you, then you should deal with the optional `priority` parameter, since it exists just for such cases

Comment: Unfortunately elfinder is an external bundle (from comoser) that I can't edit and set priority

Comment: Note: By the way, you can also specify priorities in configuration files.

Comment: Elfinder should have a higher priority. It's a good idea to set it via config files. But I did not find it in the official documentation. There are examples only in the annotations. As you indicated in the example

Comment: @AlexReid I added a way with a config file, I'm not entirely sure that I specified the correct path, but I spied from this file https://github.com/helios-ag/FMElfinderBundle/blob/main/src/Resources/config/routing.yaml

Answer (score 0):

I tried to set the priority through the configuration file. But unfortunately it didn't work.

The only thing that helped was to create your own methods that will redirect

```
/**
 * @Route("/elfinder", name="elfinder", priority=10)
 */
public function elfinder()
{
    return $this->forward('FM\ElfinderBundle\Controller\ElFinderController::show', [
        'homeFolder'  => '',
        'instance' => 'default',
    ]);
}

/**
 * @Route("/efconnect", name="efconnect", priority=11)
 */
public function elfinderLoad(Request $request, SessionInterface $session, EventDispatcherInterface $dispatcher)
{
    return $this->forward('FM\ElfinderBundle\Controller\ElFinderController::load', [
        'session' => $session,
        'eventDispatcher' => $dispatcher,
        'request' => $request,
        'homeFolder'  => '',
        'instance' => 'default',
    ]);
}
```